Groups of homeomorphisms vs Configuration spaces
Let $M$ be compact connected oriented topological manifold. Let $Top(M,Q)$ denote the set of isotopy classes of all orientation preserving self-homeomorphisms which fix $Q$ setwise and fix the boundary of $M$ pointwise.. Denote $Top(M, \phi) = Top(M)$. Endow $Top(M)$ with the compact-open topology.
Let $\mathfrak{F}_{n}(M)$ denote the (ordered) configuration space of $M$.
Consider $M^{n} = M \times M \times \cdots\times M$ with the product topology. The configuration space of $M$ is the subspace $$\{ (u_{1},u_{2}, \dots ,u_{n}) \in M^{n} \hspace{3px} | \hspace{3px} u_{i} \neq u_{j} \hspace{3px} \text{whenever} \hspace{3px}i\neq j  \}.$$ Quiotenting this particular space by $\mathfrak{S}_{n}$ we get the unordered configuration space denoted by $C_{n}(M) = \mathfrak{F}_{n}(M) / \mathfrak{S}_{n}$.
Let $M^{o} = M \backslash \delta M$ and $Q \subset M^{o}$ be a $n$-point subset. Denote the evaluation map by $e = e_{Q} : Top(M) \rightarrow C_{n}(M^{o})$ where $f \in Top(M)$ is mapped to $f(Q)$. It is claimed that this evaluation $e$ is surjective and continuous (It is infact a locally trivial fibration).
I cannot see why this map should be a continuous surjection. Can anyone help me out?

What did you try to prove this and where did you get stuck? Also, you are only using $Top(M)$, not $Top(M,Q)$.

I was trying to prove that this map is a locally trivial fibration with fiber $Top(M,Q)$. One of the first steps is to prove that this map is continuous.

So, what is stopping you from simply following the definition of a continuous map from a quotient space?

Also, do you know that the group of homeomorphisms acts $n$-point transitively on a connected manifold?

oh, then the surjection part is done.

@MoisheKohan To prove continuity, I need to show the inverse image of a open set is open. How does open sets in $C_{n}(M^{o})$ look like?

Start by proving continuity of the action of $Homeo(M)$ on $M^n$.

First of all, for every connected manifold $M$ (without boundary), $Homeo(M)$ acts transitively on the $n$-fold configuration space of $M$: This was discussed several times on MSE. It follows that  $Homeo(M)$ acts transitively on every $C_n(M)$. The same proof works if you want to work with manifolds with boundary, as long as you limit yourself to configurations of points in the interior of $M$.
Continuity of the action of $Homeo(M)$ on $C_n(M)$ is just an exercise in definitions. First, you check that the action of  $Homeo(M)$ on $M$ is continuous:
$$
(f,x)\mapsto f(x)
$$
is a continuous map $Homeo(M)\times M\to M$. Then you check that the same is true for the action on $M^n= M\times M \times ... \times M$ ($n$ times), since the product of continuous maps is continuous. By definition of the subspace topology, you get continuity of the action on the ordered configuration space of $M$. To get continuity of the action on $C_n(M)$ you use the fact that the composition of continuous maps is continuous and the following universality property of the quotient topology:
Suppose that $q: X\to Y$ is a quotient map, $f: X\to Z$ is a continuous map which descends to a function $g: Y\to Z$, i.e. to a function $g$ satisfying $g\circ q=f$. Then $g$ is continuous.
It is a good exercise in general topology to prove this simple fact.
(You just need to know the definition of a quotient map and a continuous map.)
